# electron menu accelerator not working

Tags: electron

I am going through the Electron Fundamentals course on Pluralsight (Trent, 2016). I can't get the accelerator to work on my "Quit" menu item. Below is my entire main.js file. The menu is created successfully from what I can tell (picture below), and clicking directly on the Quit menu item does shut down the application, but the Alt+W key combination does not. I am on Windows 10. What am I missing?

[image: menu screenshot]

```
const electron = require('electron');

const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const Menu = electron.Menu;

app.on('ready', _ => {
    new BrowserWindow();

    const template = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [{
            label: 'About',
            click: _ => {
                console.log('clicked');
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'separator'
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            accelerator: 'Alt+W',
            click: _ => {
                app.quit();
            }
        }]
    }];

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `accelerator` String is no longer supported.  The documentation was updated in [v1.4.5](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/7750/commits/aeb774730b8df693a5d146897ab37a918bcf62c9) to clarify how to define shortcuts using `globalShortcut`.

> [Accelerator Documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/accelerator/):  Shortcuts are registered with the globalShortcut module using the register method, i.e.
>
> ```
>    const {app, globalShortcut} = require('electron')
>
>    app.on('ready', () => {
>      // Register a 'CommandOrControl+Y' shortcut listener.
>      globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Y', () => {
>        // Do stuff when Y and either Command/Control is pressed.
>      })
>    })
> ```

**So change your code to this**

```
const electron = require('electron');

const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const Menu = electron.Menu;
const globalShortcut = electron.globalShortcut;

app.on('ready', _ => {
    new BrowserWindow();

    // Declare shortcuts
    globalShortcut.register('Alt+W', () => app.quit());

    const template = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [{
            label: 'About',
            click: _ => {
                console.log('clicked');
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'separator'
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            click: _ => {
                app.quit();
            }
        }]
    }];

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```

Comment: `no longer necessary` implies that it is still possible to use the old method, and furthermore it also implies that it's a good thing that you are no longer able to associate a single function which two different methods of invoking it.

Comment: @Michael Good catch!  Edited to clarify it's no longer supported.

Comment: Beware that globalShortcut is *not* a replacement for menu shortcuts (which are meant to affect just the focused window). It will install a global shortcut at the OS level (that is, will pervent any other app from using that shorcut). More details here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8491

Answer (score 0):

looks like on Windows it needs something loaded on the `BrowserWindow`. Placing the `loadURL` make it work. Need to try something besides `loadURL` though..

```
app.on('ready', _ => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()

    mainWindow.loadURL('https://github.com')

   const name = electron.app.getName()

    const template = [
        {
            label: name,
            submenu: [{
                label: `About ${name}` ,
                click: console.log('clicked!')
            },{
                type:'separator'
            },{
                label:'Quit',
                click: _ =>{
                    app.quit()                    
                },
                accelerator:'CmdOrCtrl+Q'
            }
            ]
        }        
    ]

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
     })
```